# Plutus tutorial similar to Ethereums "CryptoZombies"

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, learning

Is anyone aware of a similar tutorial as Ethereum's "CryptoZombies" being built for Plutus on Cardano? I'm currently in the Pioneer program, and although we're incredibly lucky to have Lars as an instructor, it is much easier to scale a programming language learning curve through repetition and "DIY" (Lars even says this for himself). I found learning the initial foundations of Solidity through the "CryptoZombie" tutorial to be an EXCELLENT way to grasp the syntax and rudimentary design patterns to create smart contracts for Ethereum

A similar learning mechanism for Plutus would bring thousands of developers from the imperative language space into Cardano's ecosystem at scale

Comment: +1 Welcome to our community! However "Is anyone aware of a similar tutorial as Ethereum's "CryptoZombies" being built for Plutus on Cardano?" is not a very specific question, so I'm just warning that if you don't make some improvements to the question you might get canned by others (not me).

Comment: I am sure there is nothing like that at the moment. I would love to see this.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe anything like this exists yet. We're still a nascent community.

A tutorial like CryptoZombies would definitely be useful and well received, but I will point out that Plutus is still evolving quickly, and I think that is a big reason the PPP is being run the way it is (instead of a static course).

Open-sourcing a course like CryptoZombies might be a great way to go, since Plutus knowledge is still very disperse. I'm sure there are many developers that would pitch in, but it might be too early for it to be worth the upkeep.